# Expo/GenyMotion throws "ADB server didn't ACK" when running project

Tags: linux, ubuntu, react-native, genymotion, expo

I'm trying to set up a React Native project using GenyMotion and Expo on Ubuntu. However, when I click the 'Device' button in Expo to package the app onto the emulator, I get the following error in the Expo console:

[image: ADB Server didn't ACK error]

I initially tried to use React Native through Android Studio, with the inbuilt Android emulator, so I thought the issue might that my computer hasmultiple ADB versions (when I ran `$ adb --start-server` from the terminal, it'd run the Android Studio binary, not the GenyMotion one). So I:

- Removed everything Android Studio related that I could find, including the SDK at `Android/Sdk/` and now `$ adb --start-server`
- Ran `$ sudo apt-get remove adb android-tools-adb`
- Set the filepath for the Android SDK in GenyMotion to my GenyMotion Android SDK. But I'm guessing is the same as the default setting, so I don't know if I needed to do this?

  [image: GenyMotion Android SDK]
- Removed all path variables related to Android Studio from my `.bashrc` file, including `$ANDROID_HOME`. (should I instead set `$ANDROID_HOME` to point to the GenyMotion Android SDK?

After doing the above, `$ ps -aux | grep 5037` outputs the following:

[image: ps output]

even after quitting GenyMotion and Expo, so it looks like there is still a forked ADB daemon running. If I `cd` to my GenyMotion SDK and run `$ ./adb kill-server` (after quitting GM and Expo) that process doesn't show up in the output of `ps` anymore. However, interestingly, if I run `$ ./adb start-server` I get this:

[image: ADB out of date]

But I don't know how to udpate the GenyMotion version of ADB. This also seems to indicate there are different ADB server and client programs. Is this correct? I have only ever interacted with the `adb` binary in the SDK folders.

UPDATE: I tried starting ADB from the terminal again, and cannot recreate the conflicting version error. The server starts perfectly now.

I was also having trouble with tunneling not working in Expo, so I've changed the host to localhost. It works, but I'm not sure exactly what the implications of this change are:

[image: Expo host change]

Obviously, I'm pretty new to Android development, and GenyMotion/Expo in particular. But I think I've been pretty thorough in my troubleshooting. What else can I try?

Comment: You got any solution for this mate?

Comment: @DeepakSingh Yeah, I've now answered my post with what I eventually got it working for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, at least for me, was that I needed to add `export PATH="/home/darik/projects/android/genymotion/tools:$PATH"` to my `.bashrc` file. I'm guessing the reason the ADB server wasn't ACKing was that Expo couldn't find the ADB server in my path env variable.

Comment: I've installed Genymotion and added a virtual device. Under the setting for adb I've pointed to the /opt/genymobile/genymotion/tools path. What you have left here to do in .bashrc file I've done that too with the path set same as mentioned above. Now when start the expo and do "Install Android App" I get this error. 
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
Here now I'm not sure about both the paths which I've set. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you need the `/tools` at the end of your ADB settings. Try just `/opt/genymobile/genymotion` or just selecting the 'Use Genymotion Android tools (default)' radio button instead, since I'm pretty sure that they both mean the same thing.

Comment: In the expo when go to expo menu and click on the Install andriod App it still gives me same error.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me, was that I have multiple adb installed on the system.
And the adb version on my system is different from the adb version on the android sdk platform-tools.

I just add on PATH the right folder  C:\\Ragnulf\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have only one adb version added to your path, the one you need to use.
For me I removed the old ADB that I had installed, then I setup android sdk tools for Genymotion, read this article from their site [Genymotion: Setup sdk tools with or without android studio](https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/02_Application/)

After installation of the tools:

For windows add to your environment path, the path to platform-tools

```
C:\<username>\path\to\android\sdk\platform-tools
```

For Linux or MacOS just add the following to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or whaterver file is read by your terminal on initialization like:

```
export PATH="/path/to/android-sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
```

Platform tools is a subfolder within the Andorid SDK tools target installation folder, target folder looks like:

```
android-sdk
├── build-tools
├── emulator
├── licenses
├── patcher
├── platform-tools
└── tools
```